# How to get a specific attribute value content on each loop jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Can anyone tell me how I can get all the values on a specific attribute value on each loop ? I'm trying to get all the html values on each loop that has the specific attribute value( data-product=momentum-shorts ) `<p>Two-Way Stretch </p>` in this case..

This is my code

```
<script>
    jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".compare-main .compare-products").each(function(){
                $(this).each(function(){
                    console.log($(this).html());
                })
            });
        });
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) :

```js
$(".compare-main .compare-products [data-product='momentum-shorts']").each(function(){
  console.log($(this).html().trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="compare-main">
  <div class="compare-products">
    <div data-product="momentum-shorts">
      <p>Two-Way Stretch</p>
    </div>
    <div data-product="foo">
      <p>foo</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="compare-products">
    <div data-product="bar">
      <p>bar</p>
    </div>
    <div data-product="momentum-shorts">
      <p>Medium Weight</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @TeikCheah You should not use comments to ask another question. But you could use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) or string concatenation (i.e.: `$("[data-product='" + yourVar + "']");`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [jQuery `attr()` method](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).data('column')` or `$(this).data('product')`

[.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

Comment: I want the output to be <p> Two-Way Stretch </p> & <p> Medium Weight </p> etc etc

Comment: do the logic from above like `if ($(this).data('product') === 'momentum-shorts')) { console.log($(this).html()); }`